# mmap() failed: Cannot allocate memory size: 268435456 offset: 2684354560 on RealmSwift 2.10.2

Tags: ios, swift, realm, xcode9

My realm was growing up so much so I have an exception for memory allocation size. My realm size is about 3.2 GB so I put this realm's configuration to resolve this:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
        // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
        // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
        schemaVersion: 11,

        // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with
        // a schema version lower than the one set above
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

    },shouldCompactOnLaunch: {totalBytes, usedBytes -> Bool in
        guard totalBytes > 10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 else { return false }
        guard Double(usedBytes) / Double(totalBytes) < 0.5 else { return false }
        print("Should compact Realm database: \(usedBytes) / \(totalBytes)")
        return true

    })

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

However, the issue still occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess goes for that you are missing the `autoreleasepool` in your `dispatch async` methods.

The [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) shows that you should do that though.

```
// Query and update from any thread
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
    autoreleasepool { // <-- !!!
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
        try! realm.write {
            theDog!.age = 3
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility of course is that you're inserting about 100000 objects many times without cutting them into batches of ~1000.

Another possibility is inserting every single item in its own transaction.

So like, super-large transactions can allocate a lot of space, but inserting each item one by one takes up lots of space too, hence the middle-ground.

Comment: How can I cutting them? I didn't forget the autoreleasepool :/

Comment: You didn't forget the autoreleasepool? Hrm :| okay, how much data do you have (roughly)? What is the size of your Realm file after compacting? Are you sure that it compacted?

Comment: Also, another question is how many threads you have the Realm open on, and if you do the inserts in batches or you start a new `realm.write()` for each item (which is pretty bad)

Comment: I'm using multithreadingPromises with PromiseKit framework. Maybe, This is the error?

Comment: You mean https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit ? You might need `autoreleasepool` for the Realms you open in the promises as well.

Comment: Ok, that's correct. The issue was for using recursive promises. So if there's no fulfill finish, realm might be write all the time until to mmap failure's exception. Thanks a lot @EpicPandaForce

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'm using PromiseKit & Realm. My apps have the same crashes before and after I add the `shouldCompactOnLaunch`, and I do forget autorelease block. So I need the `autoreleasepool` even if I already compact on launch? And should I use autorelease block in every `then` block, or only `then(on: notMainQueue)` block? In PromiseKit, block in then is dispatch to main queue by default. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlfredoLucoG Sorry I don't understand what 'So if there's no fulfill finish, realm might be write all the time until to mmap failure's exception.' means?